# I want at click to change class “active”,

Tags: jquery

I have a question, I made a website, a theme of one page, and I want at click to change class “active”, every section pressed (about, portfolio …)

i use menuzord menu

I tried this code but it does not work, you help me, please

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

  $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

});

function onScroll(event){
      var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
      $('.menuzord-menu li').each(function () {
          var currLink = $(this);
          var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
          if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + 
            refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
              $('menuzord-menu li').removeClass("active");
              currLink.addClass("active");
          }
          else{
              currLink.removeClass("active");
          }
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
function onScroll(event){
      var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
      $('.menuzord-menu li').removeClass("active");
      $('.menuzord-menu li').each(function () {
          var currLink = $(this);
          var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
          if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + 
            refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
              $('menuzord-menu li').removeClass("active");
              currLink.addClass("active");
          }
      });
  }
```

Comment: does not work, i tryed a lot of codes but did not work   ; i do not know why